# Log Analytics configuration via az cli / PowerShell?

Tags: azure-log-analytics

is there a way to programmatically (az cli, PowerShell) to retrieve the following information:

[image: Log Analytics Agent config]

[image: Event Log settings]

Comment: Please mention the commands what you have tried and the result/error you got so that community will help you out

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ever in the need to achieve the above you can refer to `Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace` and `Get-AzOperationalInsightsDataSource`. Wrote a simple PowerShell script that output the Log Analytics workspace plus Event Log settings in tabular format.